# VBA-Excel : Conditional message box popup every 2 minutes from NOW

Tags: vba, loops, datetime, messagebox, userform

I have been trying to work things out with NOW (Date/time) but have been unsuccessful.

1. Checkbox1 when True captures NOW in textbox1.
2. From the value in textbox1, every 2 minutes i need a popup message reminder with OK as acknowledgement until checkbox2 is True. Can someone help with this logic and code? Thanks.

   ```
   Dim X1 As Date
   Dim X2 As Date
   Dim X3 As Date
   Dim X4 As Date

   Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

   X1 = Now

   If CheckBox1.Value = True Then TextBox1.Value = Now

   Call function01

   If CheckBox1.Value = False Then TextBox1.Value = Null

   End Sub

   Sub function01()
   X2 = "00:02:00"
   X3 = Now - X1
   X4 = Format(X3, "hh:mm:ss")
       If CheckBox1.Value = True Then

            If X4 = X2 Then
             MsgBox "Prompt", vbOKOnly, "Time Keeper Tool Reminder"
            Else

            End If
       Else
       End If
   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `OnTime` event rather than a loop.

Change your code to:

```
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    TextBox1.Value = Now
    schedulePopup
End If
```

And to a Module add:

```
Public Sub schedulePopup()
    '// schedule popup
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:20"), "popupMessage", , True
End Sub

Public Sub popupMessage()
    If Not YourUserForm Is Nothing Then
        If YourUserForm.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
            MsgBox "Time Keeper Tool Reminder"
            '// schedule next
            schedulePopup
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Alex. This works like a charm! I tried this code separately and now i am going to do some modifications to my code and add it. Can you email me @ mohammedagashiwala@gmail.com so that i can share with you that i am doing.